# C# Deploying inconsistently

Tags: c#, windows, deployment, installation, exe

I've developed an application in c# and created an installer for it with advanced installer. 
The installer puts the application exe along with all the dependent dll's in a folder in program files and creates a shortcut on the desktop. It also installs .net 4.5 through a redistribute if it is not already installed. 
I have then tested this installer on 5 separate PC's. 4 running windows 7 and 1 running vista. The installer and application run perfectly on 3 of the windows 7 pc's. But when I try to run the installed exe on the last windows 7 machine, or the vista machine, windows brings up a "(Application name) has stopped working" error.

I have no idea where to look now, I've spent 3 days googling and checking dependencies ect, so any help would be awesome

Comment: So is it failing prior to any window opening?

Comment: Yes it is failing as soon as i try to launch the .exe

Comment: Then check your constructors or form loading events for anything that might have some questionable code. You might need some error protection add to some code. You can also start tracing and writing error to a log then you will know for sure

Comment: The very first line of my form constructor is InitialiseComponent() and the program class is just the default, so if it was a programming error it would at least display the form before crashing, right? and this wouldn't really explain the inconsistency between machines either?

Comment: Any code that works on file IO, or registry?

Comment: are you targeting X86, x64, or Any_CPU?

Comment: AHA! thanks DonA, you've got me back on the right track now, I just put my whole constructor in a try catch statement and it will launch on the problem pc's now, it had never occurred to me that it might be caused by the code itself, since it works on the other pc's. I do stream in two serialized object files in the constructor, why would that be causing an error only on some pc's?

Comment: also, im compiling to Any_CPU

Comment: hmm so on some vista / windows 7 machines you crash when you access files? sounds like User Account Control maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Try/Catch` to find and report the error.

```
  try
  {
    //some code 
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //report error
  }
```